# How can I reference an installed pkg VF page in an OnClick Javascript Detail Button

Tags: visualforce, javascript, onclick, global-variables

I need to update this hardcoded url before an instance refresh and I am having difficulties finding a solution.

The VF page is from a managed package that has the namespace of scl

I have tried to use the URLFOR function with the $Page Global Variable but it errors on the $Page. reference

```
var url = '{!URLFOR($Page.scl_Simple_Comment_List, null, [Id=Case.Id])}';
```

Here is the onclick javascript that is in the button today that I need to change so it no longer has a hardcoded reference to the instance

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/30.0/integration.js")} 

var url = 'https://scl.na28.visual.force.com/apex/Simple_Comment_List?Id={!Case.Id}'; 

if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) { 
// Use the results primary tab id and open a new subtab 
var openSubtab = function(result){ 
sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id, url, true, 'Case Comments', null); 
}; 
sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab); 
} else { 
window.open(url,'_blank'); 
}
```

Comment: Make sure you add the package namespace.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I tried it via the URLFOR and $Page.  scl at the beginning of the page name is the namespace

Comment: My prior answer was actually incorrect, so I deleted it and replaced it with a new version that should do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't need the server name, $Page, or URLFOR; both your browser and the Service Console accepts relative URLs, so this code should work:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/30.0/integration.js")} 
var url = '/apex/scl__Simple_Comment_List?Id={!Case.Id}'; 

if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) { 
  // Use the results primary tab id and open a new subtab 
  sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function(result){ 
    sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id, url, true, 'Case Comments', null); 
  }); 
} else { 
  window.open(url,'_blank'); 
}
```

When you use `/apex/namespace__pagename`, Salesforce automatically redirects to the correct namespaced URL (e.g. `scl.na28.visual.force.com`).